# How to delete all directories inside a directory except for files, (safely)?

Tags: directory, make, rm, delete

### Environment

System: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.

Shell: Bash version 4.4.19(1).

---

### Problem

Along with hundreds of testing scenarios, I must have created countless of *temporary* installation directories with files as their content, which I need to delete every time manually. It looks like this:

```sh
$ ls --group-directories-first --classify

test1/  test2/  testA/  testFin/  decrypt-file-aes256*  encrypt-file-aes256*  Makefile  openssl-encryption.tar.xz  openssl-encryption.tar.xz.asc  SHA512SUM
```

I want to automatize this cleanup process.

---

### Progress

I have found the `find` command can be very useful, e.g.:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This, in my early tests from the terminal, showed to be working, but before I put it into my Makefile, clean target, I want to ask if there is any safety measure I should take into account?

---

That example, however, produces a small error:

```sh
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
```

How to go about being more specific here?

---

### Current re-factored 'clean' Makefile target

```sh
clean:

    @echo; tput bold; tput setaf 3; echo Target: $@; tput sgr0; echo

    @if [ $$(id --user) -eq 0 ]; then \
        tput bold; tput setaf 1; echo "ERROR: Target '$@' has to be run as normal user!"; tput sgr0; echo; exit 1; \
    fi

    @if [ ! -f .safeclean-$(distrib_name) ]; then \
        tput bold; tput setaf 1; echo "ERROR: Target '$@' has to be run from within its Makefile's directory!"; tput sgr0; echo; exit 1; \
    fi

    @ls -l | grep '^d' > /dev/null || echo "There are no more directories."

    @for dir in *; do \
        if [ -d "$$dir" ]; then rm --force --recursive --verbose "$$dir"; fi \
    done

    @rm --force --verbose $(distrib_name).tar.xz $(distrib_name).tar.xz.asc

    @echo; tput bold; tput setaf 2; echo "Ok. Directory clean successful."; tput sgr0
```

---

### Example output (visual)

[image: Example output (visual)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please be extra careful before doing `find` + `rm` in a Makefile.

Having said that, you may find it easier to script it:

```sh
myclean:
        test -f .safefile && \
        for fn in * ; do \
                test -d "$$fn" && rm -rf "$$fn" ; \
        done
```

Where `.safefile` is a file that should exist in your top-level directory. It will ensure that you don't run this from a different location by mistake.

The additional benefit is that you can also add logic to it when you need to.

Comment: The loop could possibly be removed and replaced by `rm -rf */` unless there are several thousands of directories. If the directories are all called `test*` (as in the question), then `rm -rf test*/` would do it.